# Como borrar letra por letra de una palabra al picar Boton Borrar en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, botón, delete

Hola buen dia es una pregunta bastante sencilla de resolver pero buscandolo aqui no eh llegado a encontrar la respuesta y sobretodo no eh encontrado algo que se relacione.

Ejemplo: Tengo una Palabra APPLE y deseo que la palabra APPLE al presionar el boton de borrar que borre letra por letra primero la E y dar click al boton de borrar nuevamente  la L tengo un codigo en si pero me borra toda la palabra completa.

```
    public class numeros extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private EditText et1;
        private ImageView 100, 200;
        private Button borrar;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate((savedInstanceState));
            setContentView(R.layout.numeros);
    
            100 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.100);
            200 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.200);
            borrar = (button) findViewById(R.id.borrar);
            curr = "";

 borrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    curr =  "" ;
                    displayOne();
    
                }
            });  
  
     100.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    curr = curr + "100 " ;
                    displayOne();
                }
            });
    
     200.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    curr = curr + "200 " ;
                    displayOne();
                }
            });public void displayOne(){
            et1.setText(curr);
```

Answer (score 0):

No muestras un codigo mínimamente reproducible... Aún así, lo que explicas que quieres hacer es bastante fácil.

En java, sería algo así, solo tienes que adaptarlo para tu proyecto.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    StringBuilder curr = new StringBuilder("APPLE");
        
        for (int i = curr.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            curr.deleteCharAt(i);
            System.out.print(curr + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Un saludo

---

**Para el segundo caso que planteas:**

Fijate en este código:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    StringBuilder curr = new StringBuilder("APPLE, apple");
    
    String[] currSeparado = curr.toString().split(", ");
    
        for (int i = currSeparado.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(currSeparado[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}

// El output de este código será:
// apple
// APPLE
```

Para hacer lo que dices, se hace lo que se conoce como un `split()` de la cadena de texto. (que da como resultado un Array[] para cada elemento donde encuentre la separación que cumpla el comando.

Dentro del split, como ves, le he puesto una coma y un espacio `split(", ")` Eso significa que va a separar toda la cadena de texto siempre que encuentra esta combinación de caracteres.

Un ejemplo para que quede claro:

```
cadenaTexto = "cosa1, cosa2, cosa3,cosa4, cosa5"
//Un Split(", ") de esta cadena, dará este resultado:
cadenaSplitted = ["cosa1", "cosa2", "cosa3,cosa4", "cosa5"] // 4 elementos
```

(i) **Nótese** que "cosa3,cosa4" como no encuentra una `coma + espacio` no separa la cadena en ése punto.

Así que en tu caso, si entran siempre `"APPLE, APPLE"` pues puedes hacer un split i quedarte con la primera posicion `currSeperado[0]` y ya tienes lo que buscas.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @ferter3006 muy entendible y para eliminar palabra por palabra en si como seria? tengo un edittext que viene dos palabras asi: APPLE, APPLE. a dar click boton delete quedaria nomas un APPLE espero explicarme.

Comment: He editado la respuesta con el segundo caso que planteas. Un saludo.

Comment: Ya anduve un rato tratando de arrancarlo si lo adapte perfectamente al proyecto pero no me hace la funcion de borrar ,me borra todo completo.